# Change field of json property jackson on 3rd party class

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a class in a 3rd party library that is marked as final and I'm trying to deserialize json into this using Jackson but I'm getting the

```
 org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field
```

As it is a 3rd party and final I can't add the `@JsonProperty` to define a new name.

How can I re-map a given property name to use another?

*UPDATE: mixins is the way to go, I was doing it wrong.*

I'm trying to use [MixIns](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonMixInAnnotations)

Here's what I'm doing:

```
package com.some.stuff;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;


final class Closed implements Serializable {
    private List<Other> others;
    public List<Other> getOthersList() {
        return others;
    }
    public void setOthersList( List<Other> others ) {
        this.others = others;
    }
}
final class Other implements Serializable {
    private String data;
    public void setData(String data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
    public String getData() {
        return this.data;
    }
}

abstract class OthersMixIn {
    OthersMixIn(@JsonProperty("others") List<Other> othersList){}
}
class Main {

    public static void main( String ... args ) {

        String json = "{\"others\":[{\"data\":\"d\"}]}";


        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.getSerializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Closed.class, OthersMixIn.class);
        mapper.getDeserializationConfig().addMixInAnnotations(Closed.class, OthersMixIn.class);

        try {
            Closed closed = mapper.readValue( json , Closed.class);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

output:

```
org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "others" (Class com.some.stuff.Closed), not marked as ignorable
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@28d47c65; line: 1, column: 12] (through reference chain: com.some.stuff.Closed["others"])
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException.from(UnrecognizedPropertyException.java:53)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.unknownFieldException(StdDeserializationContext.java:267)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.reportUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:673)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.StdDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(StdDeserializer.java:659)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.handleUnknownProperty(BeanDeserializer.java:1365)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer._handleUnknown(BeanDeserializer.java:725)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:703)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1863)
    at com.some.stuff.Main.main(Main.java:45)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
```

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Updated, thanks you in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of a mixin is to provide a type (with appropriate annotations) that would mirror what you wanted to do.

Doing

```
abstract class OthersMixIn {
    OthersMixIn(@JsonProperty("others") List<Other> othersList){}
}
```

would mean you want Jackson to use a constructor in the `Closed` class that has a parameter of type `List<Other>` and use the property `others` from the JSON to fill it in. But that's not what you want to do since `Closed` doesn't have such a constructor.

Instead, you want to simulate adding the `@JsonProperty` annotation to a getter in the `Closed` class. Like so

```
abstract class OthersMixIn {
    @JsonProperty("others")
    abstract List<Other> getOthersList();
}
```

Comment: I initially found this with an interface and didn't work, I thought that the way abstract classes worked was using the constructor.

This worked perfectly thank you!